# Elastic kibana with rest api

Tags: python, django, rest, elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to use rest API in the kibana dev portal. but I am not getting the correct output.
[here I am attaching my file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLswQ.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call only Elasticsearch API from the Kibana Dev tool. Also, when you call Elasticsearch API from Dev tool, you don't need to provide host and authentication details. It is not possible to call external API from Kibana dev tool.

You can search using below API:

```
GET index_name/_search
```